# Property 'sx' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CardProps' (React-card) (materialui)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build a basic card using react material-ui.

I hit 'View code' on the media example that has a lizard https://mui.com/material-ui/react-card/ and copied the code for the Card.

However, when I paste the code into my .tsx file for my project, I get the following error

```
Type '{ children: Element[]; sx: { maxWidth: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CardProps'.
  Property 'sx' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CardProps'.
```

It underlines 'sx' in red and gives the error. Here is my code. I'd appreciate any guidance.

```
import Card,
{
  CardActions,
  CardMedia
} from '@material/react-card';
import CardContent from "@material/react-card";

                <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
                  <CardMedia
                    sx={{ height: 140 }}
                    image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
                    title="green iguana"
                  />
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                      Lizard
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                      Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
                      species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                  <CardActions>
                    <Button size="small">Share</Button>
                    <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
                  </CardActions>
                </Card>
```

Comment: `@material/react-card` hasn't been updated in 3 years and will be using an older version of MUI. The `sx` property is from v5 of MUI, and won't be supported by that old package. Plus that documentation you linked for `@material-ui`, which is a different package than the one you're importing. Why not just use the `@material-ui` packages?

Comment: @Jayce444 I want to use the material-ui packages but I get the error 'Cannot find module '@material-ui/react-card' or its corresponding type declarations.' Would you happen to know the correct command to import it? I tried several but none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to install and import material-ui if you haven't done so already. You are trying to import from the wrong package in the code. @material is not the same as @material-ui.

In your package.json, do you have @material-ui/core listed as a dependency? If not, [per this guide](https://v4.mui.com/getting-started/installation/),  you will need to install it, do either:

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/core

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/core
```

Then you will be able to import the card you are trying to use with the lizard example.

Are you using any other components from the @material package? As someone else mentioned in a previous comment, that is not the same package you're following the example from.

Best of luck!